# Hikari pool shuts down even after setting 10 hours life time

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp

Hi I'm currently running a task which need to connect to the DB for about an hour(requirement).
I'm using a spring boot application and at a @COnfiguration I'm setting

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource(final DatabaseProperties databaseProperties) {

```
final var config = new HikariConfig();
config.setDriverClassName(org.postgresql.Driver.class.getName());
config.setJdbcUrl("my url");
config.setPassword("my password");
config.setUsername("my user name");
config.setInitializationFailTimeout(30000);
config.setConnectionTimeout(36000000);
config.setIdleTimeout(36000000);
config.setMaxLifetime(36000000);
config.setKeepaliveTime(15000000);
config.setMaximumPoolSize(100);
config.setValidationTimeout(36000000);

return new HikariDataSource(config);
```

}

However, when this time consuming task is called within few seconds it shuts down by giving

```
{ 
"timestamp": "2022-06-01 12:08:52.820", 
"level": "INFO", 
"thread": "SpringApplicationShutdownHook", 
"logger": "com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource", 
"message": "HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...", 
"context": "default"
```

}

There are answers for Hikari to shut down as the app starts but I couldn't find any answer for this.
Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.